# Access symbols defined in the linker script by application

Tags: c, linker, iar

In my linker script file, I have defined two symbols

```
define symbol _region_RAM_start__     = 0xC0000000;
define symbol _region_RAM_end__       = 0xC00fffff;
```

and then I have exported them as well as shown below

```
export symbol _region_RAM_start__;
export symbol _region_RAM_end__;
```

From the application code, I try to access these symbols

```
extern const unsigned int _region_RAM_start__;
extern const unsigned int _region_RAM_end__;
....
int GetRAMSize()
{
    int size = 0;
    unsigned int address_1 = _region_RAM_start__;
    unsigned int address_2 = _region_RAM_end__;
    size = address_2 - address_1 + 1U;
    return size;
}
```

Now, I expected the return value to be 0x00100000, however, all I get is 0.
So, when I turned to the debugger, I noticed that `_region_RAM_start__` and `_region_RAM_end__` have the values 0xC0000000 and 0xC00fffff respectively, but `address_1` and `address_2` have the value 0.

The compiler optimization is set to "None". This has been bugging me for a while now. Is there something very obvious I am missing here *(other than "I should not be doing this in the first place")*?

**Solution**
Thanks to n.m. for the answer

```
  unsigned int address_1 = (unsigned int) (&_region_RAM_start__);
```

Otherwise `address_1` and `address_2` both contain garbage values (i.e. values available at the address 0xC0000000 and 0xC00fffff respectivly, but garbage from the point of view of this code)

Comment: This is a correct and expected behaviour. A symbol is a name for an address. `extern xyz` means "Mr. Linker, I don't know the address of `xyz`, please resolve it for me".

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the pointer @n.m. So the solution was to use address_1 = (unsigned int) (&_region_RAM_start__);

Comment: I was going to ask: where is the `define` syntax documented, but then I finally saw the iar tag. There are other linkers out there in the world! :-)

Answer (score 36):

That's a bit old but i will answer it anyways…

From the [`ld` manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Source-Code-Reference.html):

> Accessing a linker script defined variable from source code is
>     not intuitive.  In particular a linker script symbol is not
>     equivalent to a variable declaration in a high level language,
>     it is instead a symbol that does not have a value.
>
> Before going further, it is important to note that compilers
>     often transform names in the source code into different names
>     when they are stored in the symbol table.  For example, Fortran
>     compilers commonly prepend or append an underscore, and C++
>     performs extensive name mangling.  Therefore there might be a
>     discrepancy between the name of a variable as it is used in
>     source code and the name of the same variable as it is defined
>     in a linker script.  For example in C a linker script variable
>     might be referred to as:
>
> ```
> extern int foo;
> ```
>
> But in the linker script it might be defined as:
>
> ```
> _foo = 1000;
> ```
>
> In the remaining examples however it is assumed that no name
>     transformation has taken place.
>
> When a symbol is declared in a high level language such as C,
>     two things happen.  The first is that the compiler reserves
>     enough space in the program's memory to hold the *value* of
>     the symbol.  The second is that the compiler creates an entry
>     in the program's symbol table which holds the symbol's *address*.
>     ie the symbol table contains the address of the block of memory
>     holding the symbol's value.  So for example the following C
>     declaration, at file scope:
>
> ```
> int foo = 1000;
> ```
>
> creates a entry called "foo" in the symbol table.  This entry
>     holds the address of an int sized block of memory where the
>     number 1000 is initially stored.
>
> When a program references a symbol the compiler generates code
>     that first accesses the symbol table to find the address of the
>     symbol's memory block and then code to read the value from that
>     memory block.  So:
>
> ```
> foo = 1;
> ```
>
> looks up the symbol foo in the symbol table, gets the address
>     associated with this symbol and then writes the value 1 into
>     that address.  Whereas:
>
> ```
> int * a = & foo;
> ```
>
> looks up the symbol foo in the symbol table, gets it address
>     and then copies this address into the block of memory associated
>     with the variable "a".
>
> Linker scripts symbol declarations, by contrast, create an entry
>     in the symbol table but do not assign any memory to them.  Thus
>     they are an address without a value.  So for example the linker
>     script definition:
>
> ```
> foo = 1000;
> ```
>
> creates an entry in the symbol table called @samp{foo} which holds
>     the address of memory location 1000, but nothing special is stored
>     at address 1000.  This means that you cannot access the *value* of
>     a linker script defined symbol - it has no value - all you can do
>     is use the *address* of a linker script defined symbol.
>
> Hence when you are using a linker script defined symbol in source
>     code you should always take the address of the symbol, and never
>     attempt to use its value.  For example suppose you want to copy
>     the contents of a section of memory called .ROM into a section
>     called .FLASH and the linker script contains these declarations:
>
> ```
> start_of_ROM   = .ROM;
> end_of_ROM     = .ROM + sizeof (.ROM);
> start_of_FLASH = .FLASH;
> ```
>
> Then the C source code to perform the copy would be:
>
> ```
> extern char start_of_ROM, end_of_ROM, start_of_FLASH;
>
> memcpy (& start_of_FLASH, & start_of_ROM, & end_of_ROM - & start_of_ROM);
> ```
>
> Note the use of the "&" operators. They are correct.

Comment: if you copy paste from another source you should cite it. https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Source-Code-Reference.html

Comment: I've been writing linker scripts and mixed C/ASM code for years and this one had me slapping my head. Of course it makes sense that linker symbols are always storage locations and not values once explained. Thanks.

Comment: Well explained. One minor point: you mentioned look-ups in the symbol table. I've been writing firmware in C for about 12 years now, and watching the generated assembly language closely in some cases and I have yet to see a symbol table play a role during run time--only during compile- and link-times. The generated assembly I have seen simply loads an address into a register that is hard-coded in the assembly because, in most cases, that address was put there by the linker. I know PERL uses its symbol table(s) during run time, but haven't seen symbol tables used at run-time in C yet.

Answer (score 7):

Since they are generic address symbols you are trying to access and not necessarily pointers to a specific type, you don't want to declare them unsigned int, rather declare them as

extern void _region_RAM_START;

then &_region_RAM_START will have the appropriate type 'void *'.

Comment: These days I seem to get "warning: taking address of expression of type 'void'" for that

Comment: You can use 'extern const void' to suppress the warning.

Answer (score 3):

Below code should works as expected:

```
extern const volatile unsigned int _region_RAM_start__;

extern const volatile unsigned int _region_RAM_end__;

....
int GetRAMSize()

{

int size = 0;

unsigned int address_1 = &_region_RAM_start__;

unsigned int address_2 = &_region_RAM_end__;

size = address_2 - address_1 + 1U;

return size;

}
```

Comment: if `_region_RAM_end__` is a `unsigned int`, the expression `&_region_RAM_end__` is a `unsigned int*` and can't be assigned to a `unsigned int address_2`. Check your compiler message output.