# arm-none-eabi-gcc (error: initializer element is not constant)

Tags: c, linux, cortex-m, arm-none-eabi-gcc

I'm working through the book *Embedded Systems Architecture* by Daniele Lacamera.  In Chapter 4, *The Boot-Up Procedure*, we create the Interrupt Vector Table (for an ARM Cortex M4) like this:

```
__attribute__ ((section(".isr_vector"))) void (* const ivt[])(void) =
{
    (void (*)(void))END_STACK,
    isr_reset,
    // Other ISRs
};
```

It wasn't shown how `END_STACK` was `extern`ed, so I did it like this:

```
extern uint32_t END_STACK;
```

The linker script is similar to the following:

```
MEMORY
{
    FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 256K
    RAM (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 48K
}

END_STACK = ORIGIN(RAM) + LENGTH(RAM)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c main.c interrupt_vector.c -O0 -g -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -ffreestanding
interrupt_vector.c:14:5: error: initializer element is not constant
     (void (*)(void))END_STACK,
     ^
```

What is a proper way to handle this?  Is it possible to cast this to an address of a function or should I create a new section solely for the Stack Pointer?

I've tried sprinkling `const` in the `extern` and cast, but cannot resolve the error.

Comment: You need `&END_STACK`, linker is communicating via "addresses"., the symbols themselves have no values

Comment: Check this for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398755/access-symbols-defined-in-the-linker-script-by-application

Comment: @EugeneSh.That was it.  Thank you very much.