# How to access a variable from linker script in rust code?

Tags: rust

following is the snippet of linker script.

```
.data :
{
    *(.data*)
}
> ram
. = ALIGN(4);

/* Set Stack after code & data */
_stack_start = .;
```

How can I access the **_stack_start** (start address for stack) in my rust (without std library) ?

```rust
#![no_std]
#![no_main]
#![allow(dead_code)]

#[no_mangle]
pub fn _start() {
    // let sp: i32 = _stack_start; -> **This causes compilation error**

    type FnPtr = fn() -> ();
    let th: FnPtr = trap_handler;

    unsafe {
        asm!("csrw mtvec, {}" ,
            in(reg) th);
    }

    loop {}
}
```

Comment: Note `_start()` needs to be `extern "C"`, and it's also good to mark it as returning `!`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey i do not really have a way of running your code but [this source](https://docs.rust-embedded.org/embedonomicon/main.html#life-before-main) seems to do what you are trying to achieve. I suggest you read the whole thing but i will put the important parts in the answer.

They create symbols in the linker script:

```
.data : AT(ADDR(.rodata) + SIZEOF(.rodata))
{
  _sdata = .;
  *(.data .data.*);
  _edata = .;
} > RAM
```

and later declare them as `extern "C"` in rust:

```rust
extern "C" {
    static mut _sdata: u8;
    static mut _edata: u8;
}
```

Afterwards they use the *address* of those symbols this way:

```rust
let count = &_edata as *const u8 as usize - &_sdata as *const u8 as usize;
```

As for why the rust code uses addresses of those variables instead of their values i direct you to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40392131/5457426) SO answer.

I am not sure why the variables are declared as `u8`, but they are accessed by their address which is cast to `usize` anyways, so i suspect their type might be unimportant for the compiler.

Comment: If the code would not use the address, the `u8` at the addresses would be fetched.